# How to get name (uri) of all model files in project

Tags: xtext

In validator I would like to get uri of all model files.

I can get name only of current file (e.g myDsl1.mydsl) but I would like to get uri of other files too (e.g myDsl2.mydsl, myDsl3.mydsl).

Can this be done in validator or I should create new classes/methods for seeing this files?

Comment: you can access the index through IResourceDescriptionsProvider/IResourceDescriptions. That one will give you access to allResourceDescriptions in workspace. you then need to filter. you can also use IContainer.Manager getContainer/visiblecontainers and then getResourceDescriptions on the containers.

Comment: Thank you, it worked. I injected IResourceDescriptions then I called on it getAllResourceDescriptions() and I can getURI().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the Xtext index `IResourceDescriptions` via `IResourceDescriptionsProvider`. You can ask `IResourceDescriptions` for `getAllResourceDescriptions` which you may have to filter for project.
to use std visibility meachinsm check out `IContainer.Manager` with `getVisibleContainers/getContainer` and `IContainer.getResourceDescriptions´. Check out` DefaultGlobalScopeProvider` for sample usage.